# How to index on regex substring in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, indexing

I have a table which looks like this:

| id | price | barcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | A_100-15437859603-233 |
| 2 | 200 | A_123-49875452222-128 |
| 3 | 180 | A_231-21284568323-367 |
| 4 | 150 | B_122457 |

Having two (or more) formats of data in the "barcode" column. Now my queries look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE barcode like 'A_%' AND
SUBSTRING(barcode, '-(.*?)-')='15437859603'
```

In order to find the first row for example. This table has tens of millions of rows, how can I speed up this regex search in PostgreSQL? Can I create an index on `SUBSTRING(barcode, '-(.*?)-')`?

Comment: Would it allready help just to expand the `LIKE()` operator. For example something like `like 'A[_]%[-]15437859603[-]%'`?

Comment: @JvdV Good idea, but this would also be a sequential scan right? How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create an index on `SUBSTRING(barcode, '-(.*?)-')`.

To support the first condition, you should change it to `substr(barcode, 1, 2) = 'A_'`, then you can use the following index to support the query ideally:

```
CREATE INDEX ON my_table (
   SUBSTRING(barcode, '-(.*?)-'),
   substr(barcode, 1, 2)
);
```

If the first condition always compares with `'A_'`, you could also use

```
CREATE INDEX ON my_table (SUBSTRING(barcode, '-(.*?)-'))
   WHERE substr(barcode, 1, 2) = 'A_';
```